# Using SASS / BEM / Grandparent / parent / child / selector / :hover

Tags: html, css, sass, hover

I'm having a challenge and i'm hours away from handing in a project and totally frustrated.

In the past i've done a simple paragraph collapse, by splitting the paragraph into 2 pieces and inserting a toggle in between.

```
<p id="paragraph1">some text goes here </p>
<p id="toggleMe">more...</p>
<p id="paragraph2">more hidden text shows up here</p>
```

in the css:

```
#paraphgraph2{
display: none;

#togglMe:hover #paragraph2{
display: block;
}
```

but apparently i'm doing something wrong, because its not affecting the browser.

Comment: `#togglMe:hover #paragraph2` suggest that `#paragraph2` is inside `#toggleMe`

Answer (score 2):

This is what you have:

```css
#paraphgraph2{
display: none;

#togglMe:hover #paragraph2{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraph1">some text goes here </p>
<p id="toggleMe">more...</p>
<p id="paragraph2">more hidden text shows up here</p>
```

Try the following instead:

```css
#paragraph2{ /* Wrong id selector */
  display: none;
}/* Add closing bracket  */

#toggleMe:hover #paragraph2{ /* Wrong id selector */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraph1">some text goes here </p>
<div id="toggleMe">
  more...
  
  <p id="paragraph2">more hidden text shows up here</p>
</div>
```

`#toggleMe:hover #paragraph2{` Suggest `#paragraph2` to be inside `#toggleMe`.

Comment: thank you muchly .... been coding for hours, probably a carless mistake on my part, that I just couldn't see...thank you.

Comment: @ScatterBrainz if this is the answer you should mark it as such